# Seeking for more than one occurrence of an expression

Tags: windows-7, visual-foxpro

How can I search for more than occurrence of index key based matches in foxpro? I want to change the `chosen` field in table `dl` to `T` for all rows where there exists a `subdir`field match in `ctw` and `dl` tables. This matching search is to be repeated for all rows within `ctw`. The records in `dl` with equal `subdir` values are not ordered sequentially.

Currently, the code exits with *end of file encountered* message on line 17 `do while not eof()` nested loop after changing `chosen` to `T` for `dl` records that match only the first `subdir` value of `ctw`.

```
select 0
use ctw

select 0
use dl
index on subdir to subdir.idx 

select ctw

do while .not. eof() 

    select dl 
    seek ctw -> subdir

    if found()
        do while not eof() 
            replace chosen with .t. for ctw -> subdir = dl -> subdir
            skip
        enddo
    endif

    select ctw 
    skip 
enddo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your coding is very old style. You get the error because:

replace ... for ...

traverses the whole table and leaves the record pointer at bottom. Then doing a skip causes the error.

Your code, is also very hard to read and follow. I would revise it as:

```
Update dl Set chosen = .T. Where subdir In (Select subdir From ctw)
```

Comment: Don't learn from 90's prgs. 90's was Foxpro 2.x days, VFP is a different beast (like a new and different language). You can also use websites like www.foxite.com and www.universalthread.com. Those are still vivid foxpro specific forums.And even if from 90's, above code is not good, change your source.